# npm start dosen't launch or starts any react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-start

I just create a new react app using 
`create-react-app`
and it worked as well , then I just cd into this app and tried 
`npm start` 
and then nothing worked & nothing appeared in the console

1- I have tried to remove node-module and then npm install again and try again 
2- I tried to clean the cash and repeat step 1 and nothing worked 
3- I tried to reinstall node and nothing worked ether .

that's my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "ropofriend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://kyrolos.github.io/Robofriend-app/.",
  "dependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "tachyons": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try npm run start ?

Comment: yea same issues

Comment: I just tried and npm start is working, can you provide me with your error output ? Maybe you have something on 3000 port ?

Comment: That's an outdated and I believe, incompatible version of `react-scripts`... Not sure how it's possible that you just created it... for `React` v `16.8.6` the `react-scripts` version should be `2.8.1`

Comment: @SakoBu 
ok I 'm updating ` react-script ` now

Answer (score 0):

try this:
**"start": "cd packages/react-scripts && node bin/react-scripts.js start",**

basically you have to give the address of your main view file.

or this:
  **"start": "node src/feathers/"**

Comment: ```     {
  "name": "ropofriend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://kyrolos.github.io/Robofriend-app/.",
  "dependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",    ```

Comment: ```              "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "tachyons": "^4.9.1"
  },```

Comment: ```     "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```